# Cloud API access scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have created a project on google cloud platform with one master and 2 slaves (workers) to test mapreduce and spark!

Unfortunately, I haven't allowed the API access to all Google Cloud services at the moment of the creation !

> **Cloud API access scopes**
>
> ```
> BigQuery Enabled
> Bigtable Admin Tables only
> Bigtable Data Read/Write
> Cloud Datastore Disabled
> Cloud Pub/Sub Disabled
> Cloud Source Repositories Disabled
> Cloud SQL Disabled
> Compute Engine Disabled
> Service Control Disabled
> Service Management Disabled
> Stackdriver Logging API Write Only
> Stackdriver Monitoring API Disabled
> Stackdriver Trace Disabled
> Storage Full
> Task queue Disabled
> User info Disabled
> ```

Now that I want to edit this option and allow API access to all Google Cloud services,I can't ! 
I think google cloud doesn't permit to edit this one after the project's creation ?

Any idea to edit it wihtout creating an other project ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in the future who is facing the same issue:

1. Go to your VM Instances.
2. Stop the VM that you need to edit.
3. Once you click on the VM, you will get an option to Edit it on the top menu.
4. When in Edit mode, look for `Cloud API access scopes` and choose appropriate option, In above case choose `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`.
5. Start the VM again.

Comment: Here is a link to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) were this process is described

Comment: It is not required that one enable everything. Least privilege security practices would encourage only opening those that are required.

Answer (score -1):

On https://console.cloud.google.com click "hamburger menu" icon in top left corner, "API Manager", then click "enable API" and add APIs you want to use.

Comment: This is not the same as VM scopes. It is which APIs are enabled across the project/organization.